# Text disappearing after I pause a game in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

When ever my game pauses, the text hides. I have no clue why but I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
self.isPaused == true
if let label = self.label1 {
    label.alpha = 0.0
    label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.0))
    self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//Game Over") as? SKLabelNode

    if let label = self.label {
        label.alpha = 0.0
        label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.0))
        if(_hide == true){
            label.text = "hello"
        } else {
            label.text = "Game Over!!"
            label.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

My text is disappearing if I pause the scene but if I don't pause, it won't hide it.

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
label.alpha = 0.0
```

you are always **hiding** the text.

Then you run this action

```
label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.0))
```

which restore the visibility of the text (bringing alpha back to 1.0).

However actions are not executed when the game is paused.
This explain the behaviour you are experiencing.

### Wrap up

Remove these couple of lines in both your if bodies.

```
label.alpha = 0.0
label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.0))
```